# Android Loading & Playing Sound Based on String

Tags: android, string, audio, media-player

I'm currently working on a simple Android app, and right now I am trying to get it to load in and play sounds.  The problem I am faced with is that I want the sound it uses to be based on a string (With the same name as the sound file).  The reason for this is simplicity in both the code and adding on to it.

Now unfortunately I can't just slap a string in place of referencing the actual sound, but is there some way for me to compare a string to the entire raw folder to find the matching sound, or some other alternative short of defining every sound manually?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: On phone so can't dig it out but look at the context.getresources() method I'm sure there is a method on that, that does what your looking for. Create string like "R.raw.filename" and it returns it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This page](http://www.anddev.org/tinytut_-_get_resources_by_name_getidentifier-t460.html) explains how to use `getresources().getidentifier()`.

Comment: This looks like just the thing I needed.  Thank you for the link Emile, and thank you everybody else for your time.

Comment: Make sure you cache the getIdentifier result as i believe its performance intensive.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need to do this? if the files are already in the raw file, and your looking to simply have the strong be the name of the file, then any amount of coding to do this would probably take longer then simply referencing the file since the reference would just be:

R.raw.file_name

instead of:

file_name

Thats not a lot more typing, especially if its a simple app.

Comment: The app is something akin to a soundboard at heart.  The reason I'd like to do it the way I mentioned is there will be many many sounds involved, and rather than having to type many many lines to load them all, I would like to simply load the relevant sound based on a string that already exists from another part of the app.

Comment: If that's what your trying to do then look in to soundpools:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/SoundPool.html



it's a great way to manage several different sound files. but still at some point your going to have to point to the file at some point. There isnt a way that i know of to refence the entire raw folder then simply use the file name as a reference, but pointing to the actual file isnt to to much more typing.

Answer (score 0):

Try using Reflection package to check if the file exists.

snippet

```
    try {
        Class res = R.raw.class;
        Field field = res.getField(<yourmediafile>);
        //If the code reach here, that means media file exists.
    } catch (Exception e) {
        //No media file with that name
    }
```